# AngularJS: Apply a CSS class on the first element with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looking for the first index the passes through my ng-if condition which is not always `$index === 0`, and cant be solved using `$first`.

Here's my code sample:

```
<div class="ticket-event" ng-if="!item.hidden" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.event.items">   
   <div class="title item" ng-class="{'active': $index === $first}"></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a class in the first occurrence of `item`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to check if `$index` is `$first` in:

```
<div class="title item" ng-class="{'active': $index === $first}">
```

Change it to:

```
<div class="title item" ng-class="{'active': $first}">
```

Comment: But when an item index that passed through the 2nd line didn't start from 0, lets say 5, $first directive doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this via css?

Assuming "ticket -event" is a spelling mistake, and it should be "ticket-event", the css is straightforward:

```
.ticket-event div:first-child { // css here }
```

Comment: I tried this .my-root-class ul li:first-child, but did not work, so, I am looking for a way to do this with angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do:

```
<div class="title item" ng-class='{active:$first}'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-class="{evaluationRow : $index==0 && item.HighlightBorder==true }" ng-repeat="item in items" >     
                <td>{{item.LearnerId}} </td>
                <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
```

This has worked for me. Here I'm setting Css class for first element in ng-repeat only if a condition holds true otherwise 'No' Css class is applied.

In above example, "evaluationRow" is the name of Css class to apply, followed by a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `$first`

It will evaluate to true for the first element in `ng-repeat`

So your code should be

```
<div class="ticket-event" ng-if="!item.hidden" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.event.items">   
   <div class="title item {{$first?'active':'someotherclass'}}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
<div class="title item" ng-class='{active:$first}'></div>
```